# log4net AdoNetAppender not finding library file for ODBC

Tags: log4net

I am trying to use log4net's AdoNetAppender to write a record to an event history table.  We use ODBC because we have customers with various database systems, and ODBC is sufficient for our needs.  However, I am not able to connect to my database.  Here's my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>

  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="OdbcLogger" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <connectionType value="System.Data.Odbc.Connection, System.Data"/>
      <connectionString value="Dsn=Algoma;Server=localhost;Port=5432;uid=anneal;pwd=anneal" />
    <bufferSize value="1" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO event_history (description) values (?)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
  
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="OdbcLogger" />
  </root>

</log4net>
```

I have log4net internal debugging turned on.  Here's the exception message I'm getting:

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Failed to load connection type [System.Data.Odbc.Connection, System.Data]
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Data'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.ResolveConnectionType()
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an example of using an AdoNetAppender to write to a database via ODBC?

Comment: Start with setting the `value` for `connectionType` to `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection, System.Data`.

Comment: Isn't that what I showed?

Comment: Your config has `System.Data.Odbc.Connection, System.Data`.

Comment: It took me embarrassingly long to spot the difference.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by specifying version number, public key and culture:

```
<appender name="OdbcLogger" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <connectionType value="System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.30319.18020,publicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089,culture=neutral"/>
      <connectionString value="Dsn=Algoma;Server=localhost;Port=5432;uid=anneal;pwd=anneal" />
    <bufferSize value="1" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO event_history (description) values (?)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
```

I was wondering how to find the public key other than by luck in a Google search, which is how I found it.  I found that gacutil will tell me.